# send an SMS to a specific mobile number automatically after recieving an e-mail from a specific sender and subject

Tags: email, sms, office365

Using O365, i want to be able to send an SMS to a specific mobile number automatically after recieving an e-mail from a specific sender with a specific subject.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up the mobile number as so:

- Open Outlook Web Access in your browser. The standard address is usually: https://mail.yourcompanydomain.com/owa. It’s important to note that you need to go to Outlook Web Access.
- Log in using your Office 365 username and password.
  Select Options – located in the top-right of the window – followed by See All Options.
- Click Phone from the list on the left side of the window and then Text Messaging.
- Pressing Turn on Notifications, selecting your Locale: and finally your Mobile Operator.
- Press Next and enter your phone number with the area code, and without the country code.
- Click Next again and check your phone. You should get a pass code in a text message that you will need to enter. After you receive this, press Finish.

Now you are ready to *set up email notifications using an Inbox rule* Those rules are based on your criteria, whether based on sender or content :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but it in my OWA i can't choose mobile services for my country, Portugal (Europe). I'm only able to choose USA and Canada mobile services! Is there any workaround?